# JQuery scripting issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

i create a button inside body, when click the button it will create a textfield with a close icon.when close icon is click it will hide the textfield.
everything is works fine for the first time, when i click the button again it creates the textfield but close icon is not responsive

```
    $("#btn1").click(function(){
                        $( "#container" ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
                        $( "<div id='dtf'><input type='textfield' id='tf' name='Textfield'></input><input type='image' src='cancel.jpg' alt='Submit' width='15' height='15' id='close1'></input></div>" ).appendTo("#container" );
                        $("<div id='dtf2'><input type='textfield' id='tf2'></input></div>").appendTo("#container2" );
                            $("#close1").click(function(){

                                $("#dtf").hide();
                                $("#dtf2").hide();
                                $("#container").show();
                            });
                });
```

Comment: can u share the html as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're trying to make "fields generator" so you can create multiple text fields, you should not use #id here, clasess/attributes only. In DOM there can be only 1 id with specific name. Maybe thats the case.
Try to use classes. And try to make reusable code.

Answer (score 1):

You're appending the markup each time you click "btn1", this is creating duplicate IDs which is probably blowing the selector up. Maybe try having your DIVs in the markup, but hidden using CSS.

CSS:

```
.collapsable {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id='dtf' class="collapsable"> [snip the inputs etc] </div>
    <div id='dtf2' class="collapsable"> [snip] </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#dtf").show();
    $("#dtf2").show();         
});

$("#close1").click(function(){
    $("#dtf").hide();
    $("#dtf2").hide();         
});
```

Even neater would be to have one button which calls "toggle" and renames itself upon open/close being clicked.

See the fiddle, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zbnp8syx/1/), it's a lot shorter and simpler.